# Multi Processing in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Process in Java, tat takes 4 mins to complete. 10 such process lined up takes around 40 mins. If i Thread the processes like One thread for a process, all the 10 process would be running parallely, it takes around 20 mins to complete. Isn't it suppose to take 4 mins to complete since all the process are running in parallel?

Answer (score 6):

If all those threads are running on a single processor the operating system has to time slice and context switch.  That overhead adds time.

There is no parallelism until you have multiple processors to split the work.  Threads can't reduce the work on a single processor.

Comment: Just started typing the same.

Comment: Except with I/O heavy tasks which are blocked much of the time.

Comment: Threads can help on a single core system if the program is alternatingly CPU- and IO-bound.

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming that we're talking about a single task that is broken up into several smaller pieces that are all have the same blocking characteristics.  Alternating different types of tasks is not the same thing.

Comment: @ duffymo: Thanks for the effort. So JVM Doesn Run all the Process Parallely which it suppose to in a singl CPU

Comment: No, it's not a JVM issue.  This is true of all threads on a single CPU.  The operating system gives each thread a turn by switching their contexts in and out.  Users experience the illusion of better performance when short and long-running tasks are run on separate threads, because the short task can finish using its slices of time instead of waiting behind a long-running task.

Comment: the process is independent in each thread... like print 1 to 10 in all threads.. no dependency..

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it suppose to take 4 mins to
>   complete since all the process are
>   running in parallel?????

Only if you actually had 10 cores and the program is completely CPU-bound. Either your machine has only 2 cores, or the program is partially IO- or memory-bound. All of those are quite common.

Comment: My process shares a Object in common.. How  far would Tat affect the Performance

Comment: @SriHarish: that would only be relevant if there is heavily contended synchronization on that object

Answer (score 1):

The actual number of threads running **at the same time** typically depends on the number of cores your CPU has. I guess you have a dual-core CPU, hence the times.

Answer (score 1):

The 10 processes can only run **parallel** if you have 10 cores on your CPU. But they do run concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have 10 processors, 10 IO systems etc.

Multiple threads need to share resources

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your processes are doing. If e.g. one process does a lot of IO operation while the others is doing a lot of calculation operations, they would indeed only take the 4 together.

If both process are taking the same resources, they take longer because one has to wait for the resource to be available.

How long a threaded process takes cant be said if you don't tell us what the process does, where it is running, what else is running, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's like divididing up a contracting job into 5 contracts - electrical, carpententry, painting, landscape, and flooring. It will take you 1/5 the time if you hire 5 people, but if you just have one it takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

One additional thought, multi threading will only improve the time to solve a problem if the problem is parallelizable and there are no shared resources that can bottleneck the process. I've found that if something that should be parallelizable exhibits poor performance when parallelized its due to access to a shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

If only life were so simple.  First, assume you have just one CPU with no hyperthreading magic, so on your machine only 1 thread is running at any given time.  Now consider two extremes in your possible task profile:

1. CPU-bound - your task does extemely heavy math calculation, it takes four minutes to complete.
2. IO-bound (or network if you like) - each task goes off to a synchronous web service that take 4 minutes to provide a result.

In case 1, adding threads does not help.  You still need the same amount of time for your single core to do all that math. You absolutely must have more CPUs to make this go faster.

In case 2, assuming the website reponse time does not degrade under load, you might more reasonably expect total time of 4 minutes. Each thread kicks off its request, and then it is in a wait state until the web response arrives, allowing the other threads to kick off their own requests.

In practice, your task likely has some mix of I/O and CPU delays that combine to produce the "in-between 1 and 2" total execution time you are actually seeing.

You also must not forget the overhead of managing other processes on the machine (even system processes have to be managed), and operating system management of your process - which will grow just a little for each new thread you include in your process.